# mysql and redis multiple cities data synchronise

Tags: mysql, redis

My project shall be deployed into multiple cities. And it uses a simple requests response policy, i.e. load data from mysql to redis when project boots, read requests get data from redis, write requests put data into redis and mysql at the same time.

However, I want the different deploy instances can share the same data asap. I used the mysql to synchronise data, but it works bad because of the bad network. Often, data written into one city, can hardly be read from another city for hours.

I want your suggestions. Many thanks.

Comment: Hello, please provide more information: consistency needs, maximum data delay needs, how writes are exactly performed and in what "site" (city), how do you expect this data to propagate. The problem you want to solve is very dependent from the details.

Comment: My critical problems is the hours delay of mysql binlog synchronise. The project can stand less than half an hour's delay.

Comment: My critical problems is the hours delay of mysql binlog synchronise. The project can stand less than half an hour's delay.

About the data structure, it is very simple, In the mysql, data in one row is independent, with about ten fields, identified by an id, and loaded to redis the whole one row data as value and the id as key.

About the data to propagate, any way shall do if it can guarantee a less than half an hour's delay at most. The best, asap.

Comment: about the cities, hk and LA for example, my project is deployed into different countries. Synchronise over countries brings such long delay.

Comment: I can reply for the Redis side: Redis replication over WAN works well. I've no idea why MySQL doesn't the same. You may update a central MySQL server, and replicate the data to read via Redis.